# ¿Por qué en España decimos que estamos "aplatanados" cuando nos sentimos indolentes, sin ánimo?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa, república-dominicana

Es algo común en España decir que estamos *aplatanados* cuando nos falta la energía, estamos indolentes.

> - Esta siesta me ha dejado **aplatanado**: no me apetece hacer nada.
>
> - Desde que lo dejó la novia, Juan está **aplatanado**: no hay quien lo
>   saque por ahí.

Me resulta muy divertida la expresión y me pregunto cuál es su origen. Buscándolo, he encontrado quien dice que:

> [**Aplatanado**](http://diccionariolibre.com/definition.php?word=Aplatanado)
>
> República Dominicana
>
> Dícese de una persona, cosa o concepto que se ha adaptado a la cultura
>   o modo de vida dominicano.

Así que me pregunto: ¿es esta la acepción original, transfiriéndose el concepto de "calma caribeña"? ¿se usa en algún otro país?

Comment: En Argentina no se usa. Jamás lo había escuchado en mi vida!

Comment: En Chile tampoco. Creo que el título debería particularizarse como *¿por qué en España ... ?*

Comment: @Ustanak para ello añadí la etiqueta [españa], que es lo que suelo hacer en este tipo de preguntas. Ahora bien, como parte de la pregunta es saber si también se usa en otras regiones, no creo conveniente añadir "España" en el título.

Comment: @fedorqui Lo que pasa es que el título es lo primero que llama la atención. Pocos se fijan en las etiquetas, por eso lo decía.

Comment: @Ustanak de acuerdo, lo añado :)

Comment: apostaría que tiene que ver con la contextura blanda del plátano o con su forma curva que sugiere falta de firmeza

Comment: En México sí se utiliza, aunque no con tanta frecuencia y hace referencia a alguien cuya actitud es apática o bien alguien inactivo en una situación especifíca.

Comment: Curiosamente en Chile le decimos "arranado". Nada más distinto que un plátano y una rana.

Comment: En México, alguien que se aplatana es cuando se le durmió el gallo...

Comment: @JoseMaria - Estoy de acuerdo con el uso que describes, en México, pero en mi entorno sí se utilizaba con frecuencia.  Incluso se extiende al sustantivo: *Ya sabes, Marcelo es tan plátano, nada va a cambiar.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En cuanto a la relación con la palabra plátano, no encuentro evidencia alguna que vincule a la fruta -o fruto-, o la planta que da la fruta con la falta de ánimo de una persona. Creo que esa relación queda a merced de nuestra imaginación.

Lo que SÍ encontré es una fuerte relación entre el término y la conducta, quizás aparentemente, sumisa de ciertas poblaciones ante la presencia de los colonizadores. Pudiéndose reemplazar "sumisa" por **aplatanada, quedada, dócil, etc.** (1)

> ...os godos son insoportables. os godos, no los peninsulares, porque
>   hay peninsulares portugueses e italianos. Son insoportables porque nos
>   consideran aplatanados. Es verdad que existe bastante aplatanamiento
>   entre la población de estas Islas. De no ser así, hace tiempo que nos
>   hubiésemos quitado de encima el yugo colonial. En este archipiélago la
>   gente es muy pasiva.

[Vér página](http://web.eldia.es/2013-11-15/criterios/criterios14.htm)

> Lo que en la década del veinte era *aplatanado* y *ñangotado*, se
>   convirtió en 1930 en *resignado* y *fatalista* para evolucionar con
>   hipocrecía ladina hasta el *pacífico* y *tolerante* que hoy hemos
>   puesto en boga.

[Ver .PDF](http://americo.usal.es/iberoame/sites/default/files/docil.pdf)

Por otro lado, encuentras la definición de aplatanado como la que has citado para República Dominicana, aunque no se reduce únicamente a este país, que significa "**adaptado**" a las formas, costumbres de un pueblo. A veces se encuentra como "**acriollado**". (2)

Fuentes:

-**[Enciclopedia Popular Cubana - Google.books](https://books.google.com.ar/books?redir_esc=y&id=g_4vAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=aplatanado)**

-**[Un Catauro de Cubanismos: apuntes lexicográficos](https://archive.org/stream/uncataurodecuban00orti/uncataurodecuban00orti_djvu.txt)** (recomiendo usar ctrl + f, ya que la palabra aparece varias veces)

Si bien ambas definiciones implican un cambio interno del sujeto que se "**aplatana**", creo que es importante dar cuenta de que la primera tiene una impronta **violenta** y **atroz** que la segunda no tiene.

Espero que te sirva la información.

Comment: ¡Qué buena respuesta! Si quieres añadir más vínculos, ponlos aquí en los comentarios y los añadiremos nosotros.

Answer (score 3):

Quizás “aplatanado” no provenga como sinónimo de la fruta. Al contrario esta fruta tomo el nombre del latín y este del griego. Por tanto, pienso que “aplatanado” proviene del griego πλάτανος (platanos) que pasa en latín es “platanus”. πλάτανος (platanos) viene de πλατύς (platys = plano, ancho) que encontramos en palabras como plata, plato, plató... y quizás tenga que ver más con la expresión “se quedó aplanado”. En el sentido del verbo aplanar, por tanto dejar a alguien pasmado o estupefacto con alguna razón o novedad inopinada. De ahí la relación pasmado y aplatanado, como bobalicón apático.

Comment: Gran contribución. Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]